# True or False. $K_{2n}$ ( complete graph with 2n vertices) has Euler circuit.

Tags: graph-theory

I believe this is true, correct?  The reason is because it will start and stop at the same vertices.  Am I correct?

Comment: What?  No.  Complete graphs have Eulerian circuits if and only if the number of vertices is *odd*; then all vertices have even degree.  $K_4$, for instance, lacks even an Eulerian path because all four vertices have odd degree.

Comment: Gotcha, I had the logic mixed up in my head.  Thank you!

Comment: n=1 is an obvious counterexample

Comment: @crf: In a way.  It's sort of confusing because $2$ is such a small number of vertices (and it admits an Eulerian path, if not an Eulerian circuit).  I think $K_4$, as suggested by supinf (and in my comment), is both "ordinary" enough to stand self-evident as a test case, and small enough to verify as a counterexample.

Comment: @BrianTung for n=1 it's K_2

Comment: Oh, I realize that.  (You may be responding to a version of my comment that I quickly edited.)  However, I still prefer $K_4$ as an example, as it lacks even an Eulerian path, and it's large enough to see the general principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is false, if you look at $K_4$, there is no way to go through every edge. 
And this should be always false because there is a famous criteria:

a graph is a Euler circuit if and only if it is connected and every node has even degree.

but in $K_{2n}$ every node has odd degree, so it is not possible.